# "Cannot assign / must be an instance" error when creating a model instance from a CSV (ForeignKey related)

Tags: python, django, csv

(I have read a few related questions, but none seems to have the answer for my particular problem, or perhaps I have misunderstood them.) In my app I have a model **Kurs**, and each Kurs is assigned to a user in this way:

```
class Kurs(models.Model):
    prowadzacy = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to populate my database of Kurs's from a CSV. The 0th element of each row is a username. So in my reader routine I wrote what follows (skipping the, I hope, irrelevant details):

```
n = Kurs()
n.prowadzacy = User.objects.get(username=row[0])
```

Now, in the shell, when I do this, what I'm getting is, I thought, a User instance:

```
>>> User.objects.get(username='leszekwronski')
<User: leszekwronski>
```

But when I run my reader routine it tells me it does not actually have a User instance to assign to the 'prowadzacy' field:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'leszekwronski'": "Kurs.prowadzacy" must be a "User" instance.
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I considered that maybe I'm getting the id of the User, so I also halfheartedly tried

```
n.prowadzacy = User.objects.get(id=User.objects.get(username=row[0]))`
```

but arrived at the same error.)

-------------------------- EDIT
This is my whole reader routine:

```
from .models import *

import csv

def importcourses(filename):
    dataReader = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    for row in dataReader:
        if row[0] != 'Username': # Ignore the header row, import everything else
            n = Kurs()
            n.prowadzacy = User.objects.get(username=row[0])
            n.nazwa = row[1]
            n.opis = row[2]
            n.kategoria = Kategoria.objects.get(id=row[3])
            n.semestr = Semestr.objects.get(id=row[4])
            n.ects = row[5]
            n.godziny = row[6]
            n.kanon = row[7]
            n.otwarty = row[8]
            n.save()
```

I thought the details about other fields were not relevant...

----------------- EDIT 2
After RichSmith's comments below, I have added

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

to the reader routine. The error now changed to the following:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User'
```

and the error is assigned to the same line as before.

---------------------- EDIT 3:
Let this be a lesson to all of us newbies :-) After restarting the shell, everything is working. It seems RichSmith's idea was the needed fix!

Comment: is there any way you could post your reader routine?

Comment: Sure. I will edit the original post... edit: DONE

Comment: are you importing User?

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Comment: This might be it, thanks. Now I'm getting a different error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User' so NOW probably I'm getting the id. I will investigate. But thank you already!

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: no worries, if you're still doing: 'n.prowadzacy = User.objects.get(id=User.objects.get(username=row[0]))'
you're going to get an error because that's just getting the User, not the User's id, you can try doing 'User.objects.get(username = row[0])' instead now

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I thought I figured that out and changed the line back :-) and it still resulted in the error. I will edit the post to have the full traceback.

Comment: great :)
has the prowadzacy field ever been an integer field? do you have unapplied migrations to make maybe?

Comment: Guys, my most sincere apologies. To have a clean start, I restarted the shell and imported everything needed again. The routine is working now and the database is populated correctly: so it seems RichSmith's original idea was the needed fix. Could you please give me some advice regarding the etiquette now? I will edit the question saying "RichSmith's idea seems to be what fixed the error", but is that enough? If Rich posts an answer, I will of course accept it...

Comment: No worries! Glad its sorted! :)
Thanks a lot! I'll just paste my original comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you importing User? from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Comment: Thank you again, that was it!