# Reading from CSV: delimiter must be a string, not unicode

Tags: python, django, csv

I had a working routine (after a few helpful folks gave me some critical advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802319/cannot-assign-must-be-an-instance-error-when-creating-a-model-instance-from/40803135#40803135) thread) creating model instances from a CSV file. Up to now I have been using Python 2.7 and made sure no special characters appeared anywhere. Currently I need to move to Unicode. I added

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at the top of my files and everything is working nicely (I can use special characters in my code and comments), save for the CSV reader routine. Namely, the shell objects to this part:

```
dataReader = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
```

which was working before, with

```
TypeError: "delimiter" must be string, not unicode
```

After reading some older questions I switched to

```
dataReader = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=str(u';'), quotechar=str(u'"'))
```

to enforce the fact that the delimiter would be a string, but I'm getting exactly the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try with : `delimiter=str(u';').encode('utf-8')`

Comment: It's working, thank you very much. Could you give me a hint as to how I should've discovered it? [Please post an 'answer' and I'll accept it]

Comment: Haven't you moved to Python3.x?

Comment: No. I probably should've. :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your default encoding is probably not the most appropriate.

Specify the encoding like this :

```
dataReader = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=str(u';').encode('utf-8'), quotechar=str(u'"').encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I only needed `str('\t')` in my case. Are you sure you need to apply `u` and `.encode('utf-8')`?

Answer (score 4):

Happened to me when I switched the code from a file without `from __future__ import unicode_literals` to one that had it. (python 2.7)

It changed the default encoding for string and messed with the existing code.

Fixed it by changing from:

```
# worked before using unicode_literals
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
```

to

```
# worked when using unicode_literals
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=str(';'), quotechar=str('"'))
```